# Trying to use math function: sgn... error : sgn is not declared

Tags: windows, math, installation, visual-studio-2022, basic

hmm...

I imported:System.math...

```
test as integer=sgn(100)
```

I get the error:  **sgn is not declared.**

Other math functions work.

So Why?

Might Visual Studio not be correctly installed?

Thank Yall!
flabbergasted: Jhonny Q

Answer (score 0):

### Missing the character "i"

That particular *Math* function is named [`sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=net-6.0).

Thus `sgn`, being user defined, misses its declaration.

Comment: Thanks for you response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you response; Sep Roland.

That alone still gets me a: is not declared.

What works is: Math.Sign. ,or do a: Imports System.Math.

Then sign works also.